# Binomial Distribution with random variable $x$: Prove that $P(x=1)+P(x=2)+...+P(x=n) = 1$?

Tags: probability

Is there a way at all to prove that for a binomial distribution with variable x, P(x=1) + P(x=2) + ... + P(x=n) = 1? Possibly through induction or a different method?

Comment: You probably want to include $P(X=0)$ in there.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a random variable $X$ with distribution $B(n,p)$ takes only the values $0,1,2...,n$ so $\sum_{k \leq n} P(X=k)=1$. You are missing $P(X=0)$.

If you want to prove directly (without use of random variables) that $\sum_{0\leq j \leq n} \binom {n} {j} p^{j} (1-p)^{n-j}=1$ just use Binomial Theorem for $(p+(1-p))^{n}$.